# How to search in Spring Solr for multiple values

Tags: java, spring, solr, spring-data

I'm using Java, Spring, solr... trying to construct a query that among other things could find all entities where a String field "myField" is either "abc def" or "hij klm"

With code that does the following:

```
String value;
...
query.addCriteria(new Criteria("myField").expression(value));
```

I've tried all of the following and it always fails:

```
String value = "abc def OR hij klm";
String value = "abc\ def OR hij\ klm";
String value = "\"abc def\" OR \"hij klm\"";
String value = "\"abc\ def\" OR \"hij\ klm\"";
```

What value should I pass in order to match this?

Answer (score 2):

Finally this seems to do the job:

```
query.addCriteria( new Criteria(fieldName).in(new Object[]{"abc def","hij klm"}));
```

Comment: I deleted my answer. In fact I though that they was a way to tokenize AND and OR keyword with Spring Solr but in fact no it doesn't exit . You have used a very good workaround (+1).